# GROUP BY and count whether column is null

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've got a query that performs a `GROUP BY (col1, col2, col3)` and then returns the count as `groupByCount`:

```
+------+------+------+--------------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 | groupByCount |
+------+------+------+--------------+
|    1 | a    | A    |            2 |
|    2 | b    | B    |            4 |
|    1 | a    | null |            5 |
|    2 | b    | null |            3 |
+------+------+------+--------------+
```

That works, but it's not exactly what I'm after. I want to tally a count of where col3 was null or not null:

```
+------+------+------+-------------+----------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 | col3notnull | col3null |
+------+------+------+-------------+----------+
|    1 | a    | A    |           2 |        5 |
|    2 | b    | B    |           4 |        3 |
|    1 | a    | null |           0 |        5 |
|    2 | b    | null |           0 |        3 |
+------+------+------+-------------+----------+
```

Is there a way to perform this count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do this with window functions:

```
select col1, col2, col3,
       sum(case when col3 is not null then count(*) end) over (partition by col1, col2) as col3notnull,
       sum(case when col3 is null then count(*) end) over (partition by col1, col2) as col3null
from t
group by col1, col2, col3;
```

However, I don't understand why the "not null" values are 0 but the "null" values repeat.

If the first two values in the last column should really be 0s, then:

```
select col1, col2, col3,
       (case when col3 is not null then count(*) else 0 end) as col3notnull,
       (case when col3 is null then count(*) else 0 end) as col3null
from t
group by col1, col2, col3;
```